# How to force release on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm new to ARC but understand how it works and I'm trying it out. I'm on iOS so memory is a severe concern.

I have a MyObject class which contains lots of big data. I want to release it, and load a new set of data.

```
MyObject *object;
object = [[MyObject alloc] initWithData:folder1]; // load data from folder1

// later...
object = [[MyObject alloc] initWithData:folder2]; // load data from folder2
```

This works fine without leaks, and I'm guessing the ARC inserts a [object release] before the new assignment. My problem is the data inside 'object' is released *after* the new set is allocated, and I run out of memory. What I really want to be able to do is:

```
object = nil;

<function to pop the pool, wait till everything is deallocated>

object = [MyObject alloc] initWithData:folder2]; // load data from folder2
```

but I'm not sure how to do that. I could run the new allocation on a performselector afterdelay, but it feels like I'm shooting in the dark and a bit of hack. There's probably a *proper* way to do this?

P.S I've tried searching for an answer, but all results are about memory leaks and how to make sure variables go out of scope and set variables to nil etc. My issue isn't about that, it's more of a timing thing.

**UPDATE**
Thanks for the answers, I'd already tried

```
object = nil;
object = [MyObject alloc] initWithData:folder2];
```

and it hadn't worked. I wasn't sure whether it was supposed to or not. Now I understand that it *is* supposed to work, but I must have something else holding on to it for that fraction of a second. I have NSLogs in all of my init/dealloc methods, and I can see first all the inits of the new instances of classes (of MyObject's ivars) being called, and then almost immediately after (within a few ms), the dealloc of MyObject, followed by the deallocs of its ivars.
I also tried the @autorelease but the same thing happens.

I've searched throughout the project and pasted all the code which I think may be relevant to this.

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>;
    @property PBSoundSession *soundSession;
@end


//--------------------------------------------------------------
@implementation AppDelegate

// onTimer fired at 60Hz
-(void)onTimer:(NSTimer *) theTimer {
   [oscReceiver readIncoming]; // check incoming OSC messages
   // then do a bunch of stuff with _soundSession;
}
@end


//--------------------------------------------------------------
@implementation OscReceiver

-(void)readIncoming {
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

   // parse all incoming messages

   if(bLoadNewSoundBank) {
      NSString *newFolder = parseNewFolder();
      appDelegate.soundSession = nil;
      appDelegate.soundSession = [MyObject alloc] initWithData:newFolder];
   }
}

@end


//--------------------------------------------------------------
@implementation GuiController

// onTimer fired at 10Hz
-(void)onTimer:(NSTimer *) theTimer {
   PBSoundSession *soundSession = appDelegate.soundSession;
   // update gui with received values
}

@end
```

I thought it might be the 'soundSession' local variable in the GuiController::onTimer holding onto the old appDelegate.soundSession for the duration of that method, but to my surprise commenting out all of the GUI code (in fact disabling the timer), made no difference.

Is there a way of finding out at that point who is still holding onto my appDelegate.soundSession? I placed a breakpoint where I set it to nil, but couldn't find any useful information. I tried Instruments in Allocation template, but couldn't find anything useful there either (probably because I don't know where to look).

This is what my allocations track looks like, you can see the memory is all deallocated a bit too late!
[image: Valid XHTML].

Comment: Well, you'd get much of what you want by just doing `object = nil;` before you alloc/init the new object.

Answer (score 13):

This might not be an an ARC problem. What you could be seeing is your [autorelease pool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html) not draining soon enough—your MyObject is getting released, but the data it loaded is getting held onto by the pool because of some internal `-retain`/`-autorelease` pair. Try wrapping your `-initWithData:` calls in an `@autoreleasepool` block, like this:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    object = [[MyObject alloc] initWithData:folder1];
    // do things
}
// later…
@autoreleasepool {
    object = [[MyObject alloc] initWitData:folder2];
    // do other things
}
```

Setting the object to `nil` immediately before setting it to something else as Gabriele suggests might cause the compiler to insert the appropriate release before the second `-alloc`/`-initWithData:`, but it might be smart enough to do that already—if that doesn’t work, it’s most likely the autorelease-pool thing.

Comment: I revised my answer. It surely release the memory **before** the pointer gets reassigned, otherwise a memory leak will occur since there would be no reference to such part of the memory.

Comment: Right—I’m saying it’s possible that that happens **immediately** before the reassignment, i.e. after the second `-alloc`/`-initWithData:` but before `object` gets set to the result, in which case there would momentarily be two MyObjects in memory.

Comment: See my comment to Gabriele's answer: The old object is released **after** the new object is allocated (if I understand the documentation correctly). So both answers make sense.

Comment: Works great! Otherwise my code would blow up the RAM above 400MB on the iPhone Simulator. Now its below 90 like it would do nothing. Big Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is no delay when draining an `@autoreleasepool {...}`;  the objects in the pool have `release` invoked immediately.   If an object survives that, it is because there is either a `strong` reference elsewhere or because the object was `autorelease`d into the next pool out.

If you do:

```
 a = [[Foo alloc] initBigThing];
 a = nil;
 a = [[Foo alloc] initBigThing];
```

The first instance of `Foo` will be released prior to the allocation of the second

With one big caveat;   if any of the code paths that `a` is invoked upon happen to `retain/autorelease` it, then it'll stick around until the pool is drained.    Surrounding it in `@autoreleasepool{ ... };` should do the trick.

Note that the compiler will sometimes emit `retain/autorelease` sequences in non-optimized builds that are eliminated in optimized builds.

Answer (score 3):

A bit more general answer, I found how you can force release an object:

```
#import <objc/message.h>

// ---

while ([[object valueForKey:@"retainCount"] integerValue] > 1) {
    objc_msgSend(object, NSSelectorFromString(@"release"));
}
objc_msgSend(object, NSSelectorFromString(@"release"));
```

But you shouldn't do this because ARC will probably release the object later and this will cause a crash. This method should be only used in debug!